# can I add several radiobuttonlists as list item to a single radiobuttonlist in jagged manner

Tags: vb.net

can I add several `radiobuttonlists` as list item to a single `radiobuttonlist` in jagged manner in vb.net.

Like following structure:-

```
RadiobuttonList: Mainlist:
1.Add listitem: InnerRadiobuttonList1
2.Add listitem: InnerRadiobuttonList2
3.Add listitem: InnerRadiobuttonList3
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?:

`Radiobutton 1
   radiobutton 1.1
   radiobutton 1.2
   radiobutton 1.3`

`Radiobutton 2
   radiobutton 2.1
   radiobutton 2.2
   radiobutton 2.3`

Comment: yes, but it is a radiobutton list in which 1.1,1.2,1.3 having simple radio button list items.

Comment: Hmm... So you mean that there is a mother `radiobutton` then there's a child `radiobutton` that is a list of items? Right? Can you elaborate more cause it is bit confusing. You can add radio button for your selection of choices, then let your code do the rest, like `if radiobutton1.select then` and so on.

Comment: I am creating mother radiobutton  and child radiobuttons dynamically for which i need to run a loop for all child button and inner loop for their list items to get the values of selected items only using javascript.